# statelesswidget showing the error like Classes can only extend other classes. Try specifying a different superclass, or removing the extends clause

Tags: flutter, dart, statelesswidget

[here is the screenshot of the error I m facing. can anyone suggest to me how to fix it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uyFTz.png)

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow, please add the code as text using the Code Sample option in the editor {}, this will be useful to reproduce the code and many other benefits. Also please provide more details about what you've done and want you want to achieve.

Comment: And please share the output from this command: flutter doctor -v